# jQuery text() returns unwanted characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have many rows with this structure:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group col-lg-1" >
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox">
            </span>
            <span id="value">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.DeviceInstanceId)
            </span>
        </div>
        *
        *
        *
</div>
```

where `@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.DeviceInstanceId)` is a number.

I  get the values of spans connected with checked checkboxes.
With this code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reservations").click(function () {
        var Ids = new Array();
        $(".table input:checked").each(function () {
            Ids.push(($(this).parentsUntil("row").children("#value").text()));

        })
        console.log(Ids);
    });

});
```

And the Ids looks like this:

```
["↵                    38↵                ", "↵                    40↵                ", "↵                    41↵                "]
```

How I should improve my JS code to get rid of those enters and whitespaces?

Comment: use find('#value') instead of children('#value')

Comment: No difference between find and children. Still unwanted characters

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Comment: Yeah but when I change id to class and modify my code i got nothing...

Comment: Note that `parentsUntil("row")` should be `parentsUntil(".row")` (missing period) and as said, since IDs should be unique, you should use classes instead of IDs. If the ID **is** unique, then you can simply use `$('#value').text()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either:

- [Trim the value](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/):

  ```
  Ids.push($.trim($(this).parentsUntil("row").children("#value").text()));
  ```

  which removes leading and trailing whitespace characters, or
- Write your HTML so that it doesn't contain line breaks and spaces:

  ```
  <span id="value">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.DeviceInstanceId)</span>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
.children('#value')
```

will look only one level down

```
.find('#value')
```

will look more than one level down.

in your case the span with id "value" is actually two levels down caompared to class "row"

Comment: That makes sense, but if that was the problem, the OP would get an empty string back, not `"        38        "`, etc.

Comment: Both children and find in my case returns same thing

Comment: why don't you create a fiddle.